# Write out Tomcat response headers

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx, http-headers, servlet-filters

**Context** I am running a Tomcat 8.5 server with an Nginx reverse proxy infront to terminate SSL connections, enable compression with more.

On the Tomcat server i have a running webapp that contains a servlet, welcome-file and two filters. The purpose of the webapp is to write the name and values of request and response headers to the welcome-file (.jsp page) and catalina.out.

On the **request** everything is working as expected.

On the **response** nothing is written execpt for the Set-Cookie containing the JSESSIONID, if it has not already been set in a previous response.

When i go into Firefox web development tools and look at the response i see headers like

- Connection: keep-alive
- Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

So my **question** is, does Tomcat not set any response headers besides the JSESSIONID? Or is it simply not possible to write out the "default" response-headers and their values because it's considered self-explanatory that these headers always are present?

Note. When JSESSIONID is already set and i call httpResponse.getHeaderNames().size() it returns 0 (zero)

WriteResponseHeaders.java

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    ServletContext sc = filterConfig.getServletContext();

//  Run when receiving the request from the client

//  Response cookie and headers changes are done here

    chain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);

//  Run when sending the response to the client
    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String spaces = "==========================";
    String projectname = sc.getInitParameter("projectName");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(spaces + "start" + spaces + newline);
    sb.append(spaces + "Project name: " + projectname + spaces + newline);
    sb.append(spaces + "Filter name: " + filterConfig.getInitParameter("name") + spaces + newline);

    Collection<String> responseHeaders = httpResponse.getHeaderNames();
    for(String headerName : responseHeaders) {
        sb.append("header name: " + headerName + newline
                + "header value: " + httpResponse.getHeader(headerName) + newline + newline);
    }

    sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);//remove the extra newline at the end of the last iteration.
    sb.append(spaces + " End " + spaces + newline);
    sb.append(spaces + projectname + spaces);

    System.out.println(sb.toString());//Print to catalina.out       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, does Tomcat not set any response headers besides
>   the JSESSIONID?

It sets all of the other headers of course, or it couldn't work.

> Or is it simply not possible to write out the "default"
>   response-headers

You can write them in the logs. To achieve this, enable an [Access Log Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve). For example, to log the Content-Type you mentioned :

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="custom-localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="%a &quot;%r&quot; %s %b %{Content-Type}o" />
```

The problem of this method is that you have to know all of the headers names that you want to log, and configure accordingly your Valve. I don't know any shortcut. A full list of headers can be obtained by checking [RFC2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Eugene Adell. Can i ask if you know why it arent possible to write out the response headers from the filter?

Comment: How could you know the exact response length (Content-Length header) when you are still in the filter and can modify what you are sending to the user ? There aren't good docs about the Tomcat internals summarizing in 2/3 slides how it's working, but maybe are you interested in an UML doc ( https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/architecture/requestProcess/request-process.png ). You must think about a webserver in front of an application server, and there are things impossible to do (to my knowledge).

Comment: So what you're saying is that even though i am trying to write out the response headers just before the exit of the filter chain, the response filters are still not set because this is from the perspective of the servlet container, and outside this container their is an webserver "container" and it's this "container" that set the response headers?

Comment: If in your filter you set one header and read it just after, I suppose you can read it, but I am not sure of the final behaviour, as it is finally caught by Coyote which will deal with the client. If you want to know more about the Tomcat internals, please go to the Tomcat user mailing list.